# Does the use of std::move have any performance benefits?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Please consider this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

std::vector<int> vecTest;
int main() 
{
    int someRval = 3;
    vecTest.push_back(someRval);
    vecTest.push_back(std::move(someRval));
    return 0;
}
```

So as far as I understand, `someRval`'s value will be copied into vecTest on the first call of `push_back()`, but on the second someRval produces an x value. My question is, will there ever be any performance benefit, I mean probably not with `int` but would there maybe be some performance benefit when working with much larger objects?

Comment: Cast to an rvalue, not lvalue. Doesn't make any difference for `int`s. Would make a difference for classes where a move constructor is more efficient than a copy constructor (e.g. `std::string`)

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You should move into the vector if you are conceptually moving the object's value into that vector (and therefore aren't going to use that object anymore). Express your intent correctly, and performance will be whatever it needs to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The performance benefit from moving usually comes from dynamic allocation being ruled out.

Consider an over-simplified (and naive) `string` (missing a copy-assignment operator and a move-assignment operator):

```
class MyString
{
public:
    MyString() : data(nullptr) {}

    ~MyString()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }

    MyString(const MyString& other) //copy constructor
    { 
        data = new char[strlen(other.c_str()) + 1]; // another allocation
        strcpy(data, other.c_str()); // copy over the old string buffer
    }

    void set(const char* str)
    {
        char* newString = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy(newString, str);
        delete[] data;
        data = newString;
    }

    const char* c_str() const
    {
        return data;
    }
private:
    char* data;
};
```

This is all fine and dandy but the copy constructor here is possibly expensive if your string becomes long. The copy constructor is however required to copy over everything because it's not allowed to touch the `other` object, it must do exactly what it's name says, *copy* contents. Now this is the price you have to pay if you need a copy of the string, but if you just want to use the string's state and don't care about what happens with it afterwards you might as well *move* it.

Moving it only requires to leave the `other` object in *some* valid state so we can use everything in `other` which is exactly what we want. Now, all we have to do instead of copying the content our `data` pointer is pointing to is just to re-assign our `data` pointer to the one of `other`, we're basically stealing the contents of `other`, we'll also be nice and set the original `data` pointer to `nullptr`:

```
MyString(MyString&& other)
{
    data = other.data;
    other.data = nullptr;
}
```

There, this is all we have to do. This is obviously way faster than copying the whole buffer over like the copy constructor is doing.

[Example](http://ideone.com/Y2exAO).

Comment: I know this is just an example, but for completeness, a check should be added to the beginning of the move constructor to make sure `other` is different from `this`, and if that's the case it should do nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Moving "primitive" types like `int` or even `char*` does nothing different than copying them.

Complex types, like `std::string`, can use the information that you are willing to sacrifice the source-object state to make moving far more efficient than copying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it depends on the details of your application - size of the object, and frequence of the operation.

Casting it to an r-value and moving it (by using `std:move()`) avoids a copy. If the size of the object is large enough, this saves time (consider for example an array with 1 000 000 doubles - copying it typically means copying 4 or more MB of memory).
The other point is frequency - if your code does the respective operation very often, it can add up considerable.

Note that the source object is *destroyed* (made unusable) in the process, and this might or might not be acceptable for your logic - you need to understand it and code accordingly. If you still need the source object afterwards, it obvioulsy would not work.

Generally, don't optimize unless you need to optimize.