# std::move performance while passing a big string as rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How std::move helps in performance? I read that it does not copy it does ownership transfer but how it happened?
My main question is if we pass a big object or big string as rvalue using std::move , how it will help in no copy but there will be somewhere some copy in either copy assignment operator or in copy constructor?
How will it transfer the ownership of stack based object since scope of stack objects are limited?

Comment: I think you are the misguided impression that std::string stores the content on the string within the object storage itself (to be fair, that's often true for very small strings). That's not the case. The std::string object is basically just a wrapper around a pointer to heap-allocated data.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want a non-modifiable lvalue use a reference to a constant (i.e. `std::string const&`). If you want a modifiable lvalue whose result you don't care about after the function returns, pass by value (i.e. `std::string`). If you want a modifiable value that keeps it new value after the function returns, use a reference (`std::string&`).

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered here:
[Benefits of Move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193269/does-the-use-of-stdmove-have-any-performance-benefits)

std::move will do the copy of the pointer and mark the source as invalid. The source will be invalid state and unusable. std::move will not copy the contents, so doesn't matter the size of the object.

Answer (score 0):

A very simplified view of `std::string`:

```
namespace std {

class string
{
private:
    char *_M_string;
    size_t _M_size;
    // as you can see, std::string is basically just a wrapper
    // around char * and size

public:
    // this constructs an empty string
    string()
        : _M_string(nullptr), _M_size(0) { }

    // this will actually copy the string, so it's not interesting to us...
    string(const string &other);

    // this is the constructor that will be called when you use std::move
    string(string &&other)
        : string() // <-- construct an empty string first
    {
        // swap our stuff with "other"s possibly non-empty stuff
        swap(_M_string, other._M_string);
        swap(_M_size, other._M_size);
        // and now "other" string is empty and "this" string has its content
    }

    ~string()
    {
        // deleting a nullptr is fine
        delete [] _M_string;
    }

    //... other stuff
};

} // std
```

So there is no "magic" behind `std::move`, the only thing it does is helps to choose the correct constructor overload, after that it is up to the class' implementation to take advantage of its internal representation and make a "cheap copy" if possible while leaving the "other" object in some valid "empty" state.